# How to Redirect to new page in Angular.js with custom url and query string

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to redirect from PageB to PageA with some queryString to track from which page the user has come using onClick its calling a function '`functionName`'

```
$stateProvider
            .state('edit-blog', {
                url: '/blog/edit/:a/:b',
                templateUrl: 'app/blog/edit/edit-blog.html',
                controller: 'EditBlogController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                data: {

                    permissions: {
                        only: ['viewEditBlog']
                    }
                }
            })
```

**editController.js**

```
function init() {

            var search = location.search.substring(1);
            if(search){
                rObj = parameterizedQueryStringsToObjectFactory.objectGenerator(search);
                $location.search(rObj);
                dataForFilter = angular.copy(rObj);
            } 
        }

    init();
```

From one controller I want to redirect the user using state.go with addition queryStringParameter let say '`?c=c`', How to append the c parameter to the url so that it can be captured in the controller `'EditBlogController'`?

**controllerB.js**

```
 vm.functionName= function (ev, a,b) {
            $state.go('edit-blog', {a: a, b:b});
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the url parameter:

```
url: '/blog/edit/:a/:b?c=:c',
```

and then add `c` in the object `{a: a, b:b, c:c}`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Additional information should be added as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55569161/edit) to the original question.